# Linear charger for a 3-S battery management system for portable devices

Tags: batteries, bms

I was wondering if it is possible and adequate to use a linear charger for a 3-S Li-po battery (11.1 V (3.7 V per cell), 2500 mAh).

I have read many books and seen some videos about BMS but I am still confused about what is the appropriate component. I have saw that many people use the [TP4050](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) but that one is for a single cell and it is not available from trusted manufacturers or suppliers such as Digikey, Mouser, etc.

I read many resources of Texas Instruments, but they have so many ICs that I am lost about what the appropriate one is for my application.

Could I use a linear charger for my 3-S Li-po battery management system?

Should I go with a linear charger because of simplicity?

[image]

Comment: Possibe, sure, adequate, depends if that is adequate to you. Asking for recommendatios what to buy is off-topic.

Comment: what kind of examples could be considered to determine the word adequate? I can not find useful information for it on books, thank you @Justme

Comment: But it was you who asked about the adequate. It's not found in books, you get to define it what either is or is not adequate for what you want to do. We don't know what you consider adequate when charging batteries. Time of charge, size of circuit, heat production, cost of components, cost of wasted energy, simplicity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could I use a linear charger for my 3-S Li-Po battery management
> system?

Yes.

> I would better go with linear charger because of simplicity?

If you value simplicity more than efficiency and can handle the extra heat produced then it could be 'better' to use a linear charger.

However to charge that size battery at a reasonable rate (eg. 1C = 2.5 A) a linear charger will need to be quite large to provide sufficient heat sinking. A switch-mode charger will probably be smaller, and not much more complicated than a high power linear charger. It might also be cheaper.

Note that you should also have a PCM (Protection Circuit Module) on the battery to prevent any cell from being over charged or over discharged, or even better a 'BMS' with cell balancing.

Comment: Thank you for your useful and informative response, I will research more about the switch-mode charger alternative!